# Joomla 2.5 - Phocagallery and component.php

Tags: joomla

I'm setting up a site and I've run into a problem:

I've modified the `component.php` file in order to customize the printing of an article. Unfortunately i discovered that phocagallery uses the same file to display pictures.

Is it possible to indicate a file different from `component.php` as template view for phocagallery images?

Answer (score 1):

**That template file is what controls the look/output of ALL components**. You're better off doing a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_froma_the_Joomla!_core) for whatever component (like com_content) or [doing this to customize the print view](http://docs.joomla.org/Customizing_the_print_pop-up).